# How can I pass this defined value to iclude a file in my PHP script?

Tags: php

I require a file in my PHP file

```
require('config.local.php');
```

that contains the database credentials but it doesn't allow me to use some variables because of

```
if ( !defined('AREA') ) { die('Access denied'); }
```

How can I pass this and access the variables instead of forcing people to add their database login/password?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the condition is located in the config.local.php file, then simply define 'AREA' with a null value before you call require('config.local.php'), like this:

```
define('AREA', null);
```